# Compute multiplicity by intersections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, birational-geometry

Let $x\in X$ be a closed point in a normal variety $X/\mathbb C$, also assume $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay. Let $m_x$ be the maximal ideal of $x$. Suppose $f: Y \to X$ is a resolution of $m_x$ such that the strict transform $\bar H$ of a general hyperplane section $H$ of $X$ through $x$ is $f$-base point free. Then $m_x\mathcal{O}_{Y}=\mathcal{O}_{Y}(-E)$ and $f^*H = \bar H+E$. It is claimed that by Cohen-Macaulay property, $${\rm mult}_xX = (E \cdot \bar H^{d-1}),$$ where $\dim X=d$.

Could anyone advise me how this formula is obtained?

Here ${\rm mult}_xX$ is defined by the following. The function $P(t)=\dim_{\mathbb C}(\sum_{i=1}^t m^{i}_x/m_x^{i+1})$ is a polynomial of degree $d$ when $t \gg 1$. Then $\frac{{\rm mult}_x}{d!} t^d$ is its leading term.

But I got confused at this point, because according to Fulton's book " Introduction to intersection theory in algebraic geometry" (page 12, Lemma (b)), if $A(=\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$ is CM, and $f_1, \ldots, f_d$ is a regular system of the ideal $m(=m_x)$, then there exists an isomorphism $$A/m[X_1, \ldots, X_d] \to \oplus_{i=0}^{\infty} m^i/m^{i+1}$$ sending $X_k$ to $f_k \in m/m^2$. So in the above case, $$\oplus_{i=0}^{\infty} m^i/m^{i+1} \simeq \mathbb C[X_1, \ldots, X_d].$$ Hence the ${\rm mult}_xX = {\rm mult}_0 \mathbb A^d=1$ which is absurd. Where did I make wrong??

Comment: I don't think you can deduce that $\mathrm{mult}_xX = 1$ in your last line. If you go through the example of the local ring of the origin of $X = \mathrm{spec} k[x,y]/(xy)$ then everything works out fine (multiplicity = $2$, since $P(t) = 2t$), and that the normal bundle is one-dimensional (i.e. isomorphic to $k[X]$).

Comment: Thank you so much! Your example is absolutely correct, but there is no isomorphism $k[X] \simeq \oplus m^i/m^{i+1}$. The reason is that I quote the above result in Fulton's book incorrectly! The correct statement should be $(f_1, \ldots, f_d)=m$ (i.e. the regular system generates the ideal). However, in your example, there is no such regular system.